# Python-mode: Eval-Buffer [C-c C-c] doesn't run my script

Tags: python

Here are my steps:

1- Switch to Shell `C-c C-z`

[image]

2- Click enter to accept

[image]

3- Eval-Buffer `C-c C-c` to run the script

[image]

I just got the following message:

`sent: #!/usr/bin/env python...`

Running `Eval-File` works fine. It's just `Eval-Buffer` what doesn't work.

Have I miss anything?

UPDATE:

I've just noticed that before running the script I get the following line printed in my messages buffer:

`Can't guess python-indent-offset, using defaults: 4`

Which is very strange because `C-h-v python-indent-offset` shows me that it's already set to 4 spaces...

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. I'd send a bug report. This also affects the `python-shell-send-region`.

Comment: `python-shell-send-region` gives me the following error `Wrong type of argument: keymapp, "^C^C"`

Comment: I've never submitted a bug to Emacs. Where do I go to do that?

Comment: Well, since you've now got the answer, sending a bug report can wait :) But for future reference, you may send a bug report using: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. If you don't have Emacs set up to send mail, it's still useful for collecting the important info. Once it produced the message, you can send it using mail agent of your choice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call eval-buffer with a prefix argument, <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>

From documentation of `python-shell-send-buffer`

(python-shell-send-buffer &optional SEND-MAIN)

> Send the entire buffer to inferior Python process. When optional
>   argument SEND-MAIN is non-nil, allow execution of code inside blocks
>   delimited by "if __name__== '__main__':". When called interactively
>   SEND-MAIN defaults to nil, unless it's called with prefix argument.

Comment: I have put my whole code in a main() function and call the main function at the end of the code: `if __name__ == '__main__': main()`. I then do `C-u` `C-c C-c` but at the minibuffer i only see the the first line of my file has been sent somewhere, in this case : `Sent: import random ...` and nothing more happens. What should i do more?

Comment: @amirteymuri I think your REPL (comint) buffer is not visible, do `C-c C-z` to switch to it, you should see the output of your program there

Answer (score 1):

I use this function for that

```
(defun shell-compile ()
      (interactive)
      (shell-command (concat "python " (buffer-file-name)))
      (if (<= (* 2 (window-height)) (frame-height))
          (enlarge-window 20)
        (/ (frame-height) 2)))
    (add-hook 'python-mode-hook
              '(lambda ()
                 (define-key (kbd "C-c C-c") 'shell-compile python-mode-map)))
```

Comment: Thank you for that. Your function works well. It prints the output in the message area, so although It doesn't solve specifically my problem, at least it allows me to run the script directly from Emacs.

Comment: How should one add this function commented by @djangoliv ?

Comment: @crzy Simply paste it in your init file.